# Pass int in .before() to calculate if its older than x days

Tags: java, java.util.date

I want to know how can i check if given measurements are older than x days using the `date.before()` function. I've tried passing it an int as given in the exercise but It needs to be given a date so I don't know how to pass it.
Code:

```
class WeatherStation {
    List<Measurements> measurements;
    int days;

    public WeatherStation(int days) {
        this.days = days;
        this.measurements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMeasurements(float temperature, float wind, float humidity, float visibility, Date date) {
        measurements.add(new Measurements(temperature, wind, humidity, visibility, date));
        for(Measurements m: measurements) {
            if(m.date.before(days))
        }

    }
```

Comment: I feel sorry for javadoc writers, nobody ever seems to read it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-  As you can see this method takes another `Date` not an `int`

Comment: BTW, have a look at classes in this package https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes I'm very well aware that it takes a date as an argument. But given the exercise i need to pass it an int days. So I'm asking how can i do that since i don't know.

Comment: Use Java8 LocalDate or if earlier use a Calendar

Comment: Consider using Java8's LocalDate/LocalDateTime rather than Date.  It will be easier!

Comment: @ScaryWombat The exercise is given using `Date`. So the test cases the college has given to us wont work unless we use `Date`.

Comment: Maybe the method and your tests require you to receive `int days` as parameters. That doesn't mean that you should use `myDate#before(days)`. I think you can create a new Date instance based on a Calendar with the specific days added, like `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(m.date); c.add(Calendar.DAYS, days); m.date.before(c.getTime())...`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I love your creativity thank you.

Comment: @Stefan *or if earlier use a Calendar*  - I love your reading skills

Comment: A college requiring students to use the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class in 2019 is nothing short of a scandal IMHO (unless the point was to demonstrate how superior java.time, the modern java date and time API, is, but that does not seem to be the case here, sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the Date from *now* minus "x" days and use that with `before()` method.

Example:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant now_minus_x_days = now.minus(x, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
someDate.before(Date.from(now_minus_x_days));
```

In your class it should be something like:

```
class WeatherStation {
    List<Measurements> measurements;
    int days;

    public WeatherStation(int days) {
        this.days = days;
        this.measurements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMeasurements(float temperature, float wind, float humidity, float visibility, Date date) {
        measurements.add(new Measurements(temperature, wind, humidity, visibility, date));
        for(Measurements m: measurements) {
            if(m.date.before(Date.from(Instant.now().minus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS)))) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good answer. However the answer treats time as multiplication of 24h, which might no be accurate. So yesterdays 10:00am is treated as same day as today's 9am (23 h of difference). Not sure if this is correct...

Comment: That is not the case, the hours, minutes and seconds from `now` are respected while removing the 8 days to it. That is the point on using `Instant` and `ChronoUtils` instead of just doing the math with bare integers.

Comment: I think you need to assume that the input Date has hours/minutes. I do not see that assumption in the code. Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS) is 24H before now.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba AFAIK Instant is devoid of time rules (like day light savings), which is the point of using it - unless I misunderstand the point you’re trying to make